# Connecting two rings in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I've spent literally all day trying to figure out how to make this work and I'm completely stuck. I'm trying to make something similar to

[image]
from [this site](http://pipeline.corante.com/272px-CL-20.svg.png)

and I cannot for the life of me get the bonds between the two rings right. I can get the one on the right okay, but I can't get the one on the left. Furthermore, I can't figure out how to change the "distant bond" lengths so I can offset the back ring correctly so it's all visible. Here is an example of what I have (with the non-essential branches commented out so I could see what the heck is going on). The back ring is only scaled larger so I could see what it was doing. It is ignoring the `?[ringStart]` connection in the back ring because it's the 6th bond in a ring of 5. No idea how to massage it to do this and any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig{[:18]*5(
   (-N?[ringStart](-O_2N))
  -[,,,,line width=2pt](>N?[ringEnd](-NO_2))
  -[,,,,line width=2pt]%N(-NO_2)
  -[,,,,line width=2pt]?[ringTop]
  -[,,,,line width=2pt]%N(-O_2N)
  -[,,,,line width=2pt])
  *5([::36,2.0]-?[ringEnd,1]-N--N-?[ringStart,2])}
\end{document}
```

And once the connections are correct, I have no idea how to force the offset to create the perspective either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick try. It's a bit inflexible since all the bond angles are hard coded...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}

\chemfig{
  O_2N-[:-18]
  N*5(
     -[,,,,line width=2pt]?[b]
     -[,,,,line width=2pt]
       (>[:-18]N(-[:-9]NO_2)-[:126,1.6]
         *5(
           -N(-NO_2)-?[a]-N(-NO_2)
           -(-[:-126,1.6]N?[b,{>}](-[:-171]O_2N))-
         )
       )
     -[,,,,line width=2pt]N(-NO_2)
     -[,,,,line width=2pt]?[a,{<}]
     -[,,,,line width=2pt]
    )
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[Crossing bonds in chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40153/5049) might be useful for further customization...