# Chemfig: a 3d molecule

Tags: 3d, chemfig

I want to draw the molecule attached with chemfig. Could not find anything for the core of the connections. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please add the code that shows what you've tried? This will make it much more likely that you get a good answer very fast.

Comment: Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52722/can-you-make-chemical-structure-diagrams-in-latex

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe not the answer you like but I do not know an elegant way to subject `chemfig` pictures to 3d projection that does not either nest `tikzpicture`s or use `\savebox`es, in which case you can no longer access the nodes from outside. So I propose to draw the hexagons with elementary Ti*k*Z methods, and to use `tikz-3dplot` as well as the `3d` library to do the projections. I acknowledge comments by andselisk, which clarified a couple of things for me which I did not know. I am not a chemist, so I do not know what a point group `D_{3h}` is, even though, like any marmot, I would know what a point group `D_3` is. Anyway, this is an update with big thanks going to andselisk. (As requested, I add some explanations to the code. The idea is to use 3d coordinates and let Ti*k*Z do the projections. The `tikz-3dplot` package allows you to choose a view, defined by two angles, and the `3d` library allows you to draw things in planes in 3d coordinates. So we are going to draw 3 hexagons in 3 planes which are rotated w.r.t. each other by 120 degrees. And then we are going to connect them in 3d. I added some annotations to the code.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,3d,calc}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20} % sets the view angles, see the tik-3dplot manual for details 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,% use the above view
hexa/.style={regular polygon, % just a hexagon shape; the corners are anchors
regular polygon sides=6,minimum size=3cm,draw}] 
\foreach \Z in {1,2,3} % \Z labels three planes
{\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{\Z*120}{0}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords,transform shape,
canvas is yz plane at x=0] % switch to a rotated plane
  \node[hexa] (h\Z) at (0,{3*sin(60)}) {}; % draw a hexagon in the plane
  \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(mod(\X+1,6))}] in {2,4,6} 
  {\draw ($(h\Z.corner \X)!0.2!(h\Z.center)$) -- 
  ($(h\Z.corner \Y)!0.2!(h\Z.center)$);} % draw thick hexagon edges
  \draw[ultra thick] (h\Z.corner 2) -- (h\Z.corner 3) -- (h\Z.corner 4);
% uncomment these out to see where the rotated coordinate axes point to
% \begin{scope}[blue]
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[pos=1.1]{$x'$};
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[pos=1.1]{$y'$};
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[pos=1.1]{$z'$};
% \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
\draw (h\Z.corner 5) -- (0,{3*sin(60)/2},0); % thin connecting the 3 hexagons in the back
\path (h\Z.corner 4) -- (0,{-3*sin(60)/2},0) coordinate[midway](aux);
\draw[ultra thick] (h\Z.corner 4) -- (aux);
\draw[double distance=1.6pt,ultra thick,white,double=black] (aux) --
(0,{-3*sin(60)/2},0); % draw the thick connections to the point between the
% three hexagons in the foreground (with "gaps" around the path
}
% uncomment these out to see where the main coordinate axes point to
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[pos=1.1]{$x$};
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[pos=1.1]{$y$};
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[pos=1.1]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage of this is that you can change the view angle at will.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,3d,calc}
\begin{document}
\foreach \ZZ in {5,15,...,355}
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{70+20*sin(\ZZ)}{\ZZ}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{sign(cos(\ZZ))}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,hexa/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,
minimum size=3cm,draw}]
 \path[tdplot_screen_coords,use as bounding box] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
 \foreach \Z in {1,2,3}
 {\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{\Z*120}{0}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords,transform shape,canvas is yz plane at x=0]
   \node[hexa] (h\Z) at (0,{3*sin(60)}) {};
   \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(mod(\X+1,6))}] in {2,4,6}
   {\draw ($(h\Z.corner \X)!0.2!(h\Z.center)$) -- ($(h\Z.corner \Y)!0.2!(h\Z.center)$);}
   \ifnum\itest=1
    \draw[ultra thick] (h\Z.corner 2) -- (h\Z.corner 3) -- (h\Z.corner 4);
   \else
    \draw[ultra thick] (h\Z.corner 1) -- (h\Z.corner 6) -- (h\Z.corner 5);
   \fi  
  \end{scope}
  \ifnum\itest=1
   \path (h\Z.corner 4) -- (0,{-3*sin(60)/2},0) coordinate[midway](aux);
   \draw[ultra thick] (h\Z.corner 4) -- (aux);
   \draw[double distance=1.6pt,ultra thick,white,double=black] (aux) --
   (0,{-3*sin(60)/2},0);
   \draw (h\Z.corner 5) -- (0,{3*sin(60)/2},0);
  \else
   \path (h\Z.corner 5) -- (0,{3*sin(60)/2},0) coordinate[midway](aux);
   \draw[ultra thick] (h\Z.corner 5) -- (aux);
   \draw[double distance=1.6pt,ultra thick,white,double=black] (aux) --
   (0,{3*sin(60)/2},0);
   \draw (h\Z.corner 4) -- (0,{-3*sin(60)/2},0);
  \fi 
 }
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I always felt that some of the Star Wars space ships were inspired by molecules. This also explains why they can produce sound waves in vacuum.;-)

Comment: That's definitely some titanic work well done and I don't really understand the magic behind it, but I'd like to point out few things: **a**) [triptycene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triptycene) belongs to D3h point group, which is not evident looking at both images image (valence angles look uneven for two carbon atoms lying on C3 axis); **b**) "bold" line on a rotating 3D image should not be static as it's sole purpose is to denote the part of the molecule located closer to the viewer in 3D space.

Comment: Also, when drawing crossing bonds it is required to denote which one is on the bottom with a line break (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40153/crossing-bonds-in-chemfig).

Comment: @andselisk Thanks for you feedback. As you probably could have guessed, I am not a chemist. Such things happen if the OP does not provide an MWE. I will wait for more feedback from the OP. Apart from the things you mention, I also have no information on the 3d location of the points between the hexagons where the lines meet.

Comment: For a non-chemist it's still a great piece of work:) And yes, an MWE would be nice. Just in case, [here is a 3D model and a molecular editor](http://molview.org/?cid=92764) to play around with to better understand the geometry/

Comment: @andselisk Is it better now? (I tried to guess the 3d coordinates from the nice interactive viewer under your link.)

Comment: Wow, this is perfect, very well done!

Comment: Wow! This is amazing! thanks @marmot.
To make it more understandable for a beginner like me, could you please add some comments on the script?

Comment: @MohamadMoosavi I added some explanations to the code. The `tikz-3dplot` package has a nice manual, `shapes.geometric` is documented in the `pgfmanual` but unfortunately AFAIK the 3d library has not yet an official manual.