# Resizable buckminsterfullerene

Tags: chemfig

In this post [How to draw a fullerene](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506293/how-to-draw-a-fullerene) I asked how to draw a fullerene. This is a complex chemical structure and was nicely answered by @GRSousaJr (https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/184980/grsousajr)

However, I need to resize it in my text and got mess after trying to change the bonding length.

My question is, is it possible to have a code for resizing such a complex chemical structure?

My tried code was the one below. Sorry if this is a very dumb question, but I am really inexperient in `chemfig` or any other package as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\setchemfig{
    bond offset = 0.75pt,
    double bond sep = 2.5pt,
    bond style = {line width = 0.75pt}
}

\begin{document}
    \definesubmol{fragment}{
        -[::126]-[::-54](=_#(2pt,2pt)[::180])
        -[::-70](-[::-56.2,1.07]=^#(2pt,2pt)[::180,1.07])
        -[::110,0.6](-[::-148,0.60](=^[::180,0.35])-[::-18,1.1])
        -[::50,1.1](-[::18,0.60]=_[::180,0.35])
        -[::50,0.6]
        -[::110]
    }

    \chemfig{
        [,0.5](-[::+18,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::+90,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::162,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::234,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::306,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Most likely not the most elegant solution, but probably worth a try: `{\tiny
    \chemfig{
        (-[::+18,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::+90,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::162,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::234,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::306,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
    }}`.

Comment: I don't know of a generalizable way to do this, but you can use these two sites in combination with each other: https://py-chemist.com/mol_2_chemfig/home to get a smiles string for a fullerene and then feed the string into this site (http://chimpsky.uwaterloo.ca/mol2chemfig/webiface) where you can alter the scaling. Specifically, use the bond-scale and bond-stretch options on the web-interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy scaling with `\scalebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setchemfig{
    bond offset = 0.75pt,
    double bond sep = 2.5pt,
    bond style = {line width = 0.75pt}
}

\begin{document}
    \definesubmol{fragment}{
        -[::126]-[::-54](=_#(2pt,2pt)[::180])
        -[::-70](-[::-56.2,1.07]=^#(2pt,2pt)[::180,1.07])
        -[::110,0.6](-[::-148,0.60](=^[::180,0.35])-[::-18,1.1])
        -[::50,1.1](-[::18,0.60]=_[::180,0.35])
        -[::50,0.6]
        -[::110]
    }

    \chemfig{
        (-[::+18,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::+90,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::162,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::234,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::306,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
    }
\scalebox{0.5}{
    \chemfig{
        (-[::+18,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::+90,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::162,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::234,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::306,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
    }
}
\scalebox{0.1}{
    \chemfig{
        (-[::+18,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::+90,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::162,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::234,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::306,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
    }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `atom sep` parameter. If necessary minor adjustments can be made using `double bond sep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\pagestyle{empty}

\setchemfig{
    bond offset = 0.75pt,
    double bond sep = 2.5pt,
    bond style = {line width = 0.75pt}
}

\begin{document}
    \definesubmol{fragment}{
        -[::126]-[::-54](=_#(2pt,2pt)[::180])
        -[::-70](-[::-56.2,1.07]=^#(2pt,2pt)[::180,1.07])
        -[::110,0.6](-[::-148,0.60](=^[::180,0.35])-[::-18,1.1])
        -[::50,1.1](-[::18,0.60]=_[::180,0.35])
        -[::50,0.6]
        -[::110]
    }

    \definesubmol{fullerene}{
        (-[::+18,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::+90,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::162,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::234,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
        (-[::306,0.85,,,draw=none]!{fragment})
    }
    % Small-sized
    \setchemfig{atom sep=15pt}\chemfig{!{fullerene}}\quad
    % Medium-sized
    \setchemfig{atom sep=20pt}\chemfig{!{fullerene}}\quad
    % Big-sized
    \setchemfig{atom sep=25pt}\chemfig{!{fullerene}}

\end{document}
```

Result
[image: structures]

Comment: GRSousaJr, Show! Is it possible to paint the pentagons black?

Comment: @BeneditoFreire, I don't think so. I found nothing about that on chemfig's manual.