# 3D geometry in TikZ

Tags: 3d

The page [3D bodies in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz) shows some basic bodies, but is there a better tool to model 3D bodies (rotate, flip, ...) that can export as TikZ? I can draw fairly good bodies in TikZ but sometimes I'm not happy with the perspective angle at the end, and wants to change certain aspects of the drawing. A "frame model" tool with TikZ export would then be of help. Perhaps there is some package to TikZ that can assist? TIA.

Comment: In the current state, your question is quite unclear. Please make it clearer by adding an example code and stating exactly and clearly what you want to have. Avoid asking questions that are too broad.

Comment: There are `tikz-3dplot` and the `perspective` library. They, in particular the latter, allow you to obtain realistic projections. As long as you ensure 3d ordering you can draw pretty much any body, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518275/194703.

Comment: There are some specialized packages, such as https://github.com/matthias-wolff/tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere. The codes for cylinders, cones, cuboids, and so on that can be fully rotated are available on this site. AFAIK nobody made an effort to collect and streamline them.  More precisely, no one published the result of collecting these. This has also to do with the behavior of a certain user.

Comment: You can try [Sketch](http://sketch4latex.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks for answers. I do have a "work in progress" TikZ drawing but I'm not sure I can post it here. Shall I edit my original text and expand the question?

Comment: You can modify the question but more users will look at question if you ask a new one.

Comment: Are one allowed to start a similar (but expanded) question?