# Designing 3D platonic figures

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to design some platonic solids to illustrate some of my lectures. I found some packages and commands to print platonic solids, but I have no idea how to add axis, notations, etc.

The examples are interested in are typically the following illustrations from Stillwell:

[image: Sphere and axis]
[image: Tetrahedron and axis]
[image: Dodecahedron and axis]

I would appreciate any example, package or reference allowing to do so.

Comment: Since you mention that you "found some packages" it would make a lot of sense if you make explicit which packages you are referring to. You can use asymptote to plot these. Since the question is tagged `tikz-pgf`, you can also use a patch plot from `pgfplots` or you can make Ti*k*Z doing the 3d ordering for you as e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/518235/194703).

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174930/3d-solids-with-tikz-or-an-alternative

Comment: Did you take a look at the `pstricks` package `pst-solides3d`?